# Android: passing arguments to threads

Tags: java, android, multithreading

How can I pass the context and the name string as arguments to the new thread?

Errors in compilation:

Line

```
label = new TextView(this);
```

The constructor TextView(new Runnable(){}) is undefined

Line "`label.setText(name);`" :

Cannot refer to a non-final variable name inside an inner class defined in a different method

Code:

```
public void addObjectLabel (String name) {
    mLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            TextView label;
            label = new TextView(this);
            label.setText(name);
            label.setWidth(label.getWidth()+100);
            label.setTextSize(20);
            label.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
            label.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            panel.addView(label);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Write your complete class code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare `name` as `final`, otherwise you can't use it in an inner [anonymous class](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm).

Additionally, you need to declare which `this` you want to use; as it stands, you're using the `Runnable` object's `this` reference. What you need is something like this:

```
public class YourClassName extends Activity { // The name of your class would obviously be here; and I assume it's an Activity
    public void addObjectLabel(final String name) { // This is where we declare "name" to be final
        mLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                TextView label;
                label = new TextView(YourClassName.this); // This is the name of your class above
                label.setText(name);
                label.setWidth(label.getWidth()+100);
                label.setTextSize(20);
                label.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
                label.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                panel.addView(label);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

However, I'm not sure this is the best way to update the UI (you should probably be using `runOnUiThread` and `AsyncTask`). But the above should fix the errors you've encountered.

Comment: Don't forget to mark an answer as correct if it helps you; it helps other people solve the same problem later, and will help you get more answers in the future! :)